# DateFormat issue using linq query(between)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, datetime-format

I am using between query in linq. The scenario is that i select start date and end date and want to retrieve the data between these dates. On the local system its working fine but when i deployed it on server it was throwing exception.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Data which need to be entered in the textboxes format: **04/01/2015**

Data stored in database format: **2013-10-23 12:35:56.593**

```
protected void _btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DataClassesCABEEDataContext db = new DataClassesCABEEDataContext())
        {
            var query = (from a in db.Jobs where 
                         (a.Job_DateTime >= Convert.ToDateTime(_txtFrom.Text)
                         && a.Job_DateTime <= Convert.ToDateTime(_txtTo.Text)) //using add watch here
                         select new
                         {
                             Reference = a.Job_No,
                             Booking_Time = a.Job_DateTime.Value.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),                                 
                             Cust_Name = a.CustName,                                 
                             Price = a.Price,                             
                         });

            GridView1.DataSource = query;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }  
    }
```

On debugging the code when i use add watch in the commented line of code above it throws the exception. _txtTo.Text throws this exception. When swapped the textboxes between each other like placed _txtTo.text at _txtFrom.text place and vice versa then it threw exception on _txtFrom.text. In comparison the first part gets the date but the second does not.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`? And are you sure you store your `DateTime` values with a proper database type? Hope you don't store them as a character.

Comment: "en-US" is the CurrentCulture

Comment: Are you sure? `Convert.ToDateTime("04/01/2015", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))` parses fine.

Comment: @SonerGönül...the data is stored in datetime format in database...

Comment: befolre "GridView1.DataSource = query;" use imedeate window to see what query is genrated by linq. using "query.ToString()"

Comment: @SonerGönül...yeah it does fine on my local system but on server it throws exception.

Comment: @HaiderKhattak Did you check the culture settings that used on **that** server? I _strongly_ suspect your server has different culture settings than `en-US`.

Comment: @JSJ.... {SELECT [t0].[Job_No] AS [Reference], [t0].[Job_DateTime] AS [value], [t0].[Price]
FROM [dbo].[Jobs] AS [t0]
WHERE  ([t0].[Job_DateTime] >= @p1) AND ([t0].[Job_DateTime] <= @p2)
}

Comment: @SonerGönül....Good point i did not checked that...i will give it a look righ away

Comment: @HaiderKhattak: can you get value of "@p1" and" @p2."

Comment: Can you also make sure you are able to parse date string from textbox. or what you can do is. create a variable before you query to parse dates. and then pass that variable in query.

Comment: @SonerGönül...i checked it but the problem is with the between part of query... (a.Job_DateTime >= Convert.ToDateTime(_txtFrom.Text)
                         && a.Job_DateTime <= Convert.ToDateTime(_txtTo.Text))
The first part _txtFrom.Text gets the value but the second part after "&&" _txtTo.Text throws the exception.

Comment: @JSJ....@p1=04/01/2015 AND @p2=04/30/2015

Answer (score 0):

If you know format of date, you should use  *DateTime.ParseExact*

```
 (a.Job_DateTime >= DateTime.ParseExact(_txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                && a.Job_DateTime <=  DateTime.ParseExact(_txtTo.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
```

Comment: Error: no overload for method 'ParseExact' takes 2 arguments

Comment: ah,sorry, I forget about about culture. I guess format of your date is "dd/MM/yyyy", not "MM/dd/yyyy".